# why this upload code not work in java?

Tags: java

i want to upload file with send http request to php .
i test php sides on server over and over , but when i send request with this code

```
 private static void upload() {
    File targetFile = new File("test.txt");
    PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod("http://localhost/chat_upload/service/index.php/upload/do_upload");
    try {
        Part[] parts = {
                new FilePart(targetFile.getName(), targetFile),
                new StringPart("name", "userfile")
        };
        filePost.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, filePost.getParams()));
        org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
       // client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(50000);
        int status = client.executeMethod(filePost);
        if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.out.println("Upload complete, response=" + filePost.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Upload failed, response=" + HttpStatus.getStatusText(status));

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.fillInStackTrace());
    } finally {
        filePost.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

this method send file and print on console . when i run , server say :
file not selected .

{i write php side , when file not selected , this error print}

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `do_upload` handler is probably looking for the file under the name `file`, but you're not adding a part by that name.

You need the [3 parameter constructor](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/FilePart.html#FilePart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) to set both the name and the filename:

```
new FilePart("file", targetFile.getName(), targetFile)
```

Or was the other part the attempt to set the part name? If so, then:

```
Part[] parts = {
    new FilePart("userfile", targetFile.getName(), targetFile)
};
```